# Awk extract contents between two patterns with least matches

Tags: regex, shell, awk, pattern-matching

Say I have a file with some lines:

```
a1 - first match /a/
b - other stuff
a2 - last match /a/
b
c - first match /c/
c - last match /c/
```

When I execute `awk '/a/,/c/' file` I will get

```
a1 - first match /a/
b - other stuff
a2 - last match /a/
b
c - first match /c/
```

What I want to do is to get the middle part between /a/ and /c/. But the pattern /a/ and /c/ matches several lines and between these lines there are some other stuff. So I wonder if there is an easy way to get the result like this:

```
a2 - last match /a/
b
c - first match /c/
```

Comment: what is the logic here? do you have other examples? Are a and c appearing always twice? Can it have multiple blocks?

Comment: The start pattern and stop pattern matches several lines but I only want the very middle part. Say we have `a\na\na\nb\nc\nc\nc\n`, I want to get `a\nb\nc\n`

Comment: Pipe the output to `uniq` to get rid of duplicates.

Comment: but what if "ababcc" to "abc" @Barmar

Comment: Not sure what that means. When I read the question, it just looked like you wanted to get rid of the duplication of `a` and `c`. You should edit the question to explain what you really want, not just put the clarification in a comment.

Comment: so you want to print uniq elements within two patterns, including the pattern itself? Does the order matter?

Comment: Sorry for my misleading problem description. I have update the problem @Barmar

Comment: not intended to remove duplications just want the result begins with the last /a/ match @fedorqui

Comment: Never use range expressions. They make trivial scripts slightly briefer but then require a complete rewrite or duplicate conditions given the slightest requirements change. Always use a flag instead. `/a/{f=1} f; /c/{f=0}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with a range expression. You need to match `a` and start collecting lines in a variable. If you encounter another `a` you have to clear the variable and start again. Finally, when you see `c` you print the variable.

```
awk '/^a/ { var = $0; flag = 1; next }
     flag { var = var "\n" $0 }
     /^c/ && flag { print var; flag = 0; var = "" }' file
```

Comment: I was going to post this as an answer `awk '/^a/{f=1; buf=""} f{buf = buf $0 RS} /^c/{printf "%s",buf; f=0; buf=""}' file` but it's almost identical to yours so plus 1 to you instead and my slight alternative syntax in a comment!

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have a way to know which is the last time a pattern occurs until you read all of the file, it might be best to go through it twice: the first time to get the line numbers of the matches and the second one to print the lines within those:

```
awk 'FNR==NR && /^a/ {p1=FNR; next}         # last match of /a/
     FNR==NR && /^c/ && !p2 {p2=FNR; next}  # first match of /c/
     (FNR >= p1) && (FNR <= p2)' file file
```

Using the trick `FNR==NR` to distinguish the first loop from the second one as described in [Idiomatic awk](http://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/).

With this file this returns:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR && /^a/ {p1=FNR; next} FNR==NR && /^c/ && !p2 {p2=FNR; next} (FNR >= p1) && (FNR <= p2)' file file
a2 - last match /a/
b
c - first match /c/
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `>=` and `<=`, since he wants to include the `a` and `c` lines in the output?

Answer (score 0):

another `awk` accumulating lines in an array instead

```
$ awk '/^a/{delete a; c=0; p=1} 
          p{a[++c]=$0} 
       /^c/{for(k=1;k<=c;k++) print a[k]; exit}' file

a2 - last match /a/
b
c - first match /c/
```